# How to create a trigger to find first day of the year?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table reservation details which has columns and one of the column is creation date.
I want to create a trigger which checks whether the creation date is first day of the year. If  it is then, insert values into to master_ids table. I have created a trigger but don't know whether its correct or not. My project is in php.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON ColdStorage.ReservationDetails
    FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     IF NEW.creationdate = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') then 
             UPDATE master_ids SET nextOccId="1",nextResId="1",nextAgrnoId="1",nextRecNo="1";
     END if;
 END;
```

Please suggest me some solutions. I also want that if the date is 01-01-yy then.. its should not insert the row which i m inserting.

Comment: Did you test it?  Does it work as expected?  Do you get any error messages if not?

Comment: yes it is giving me errors

Comment: is the logic correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the delimiter. MySQL sees the first ; as the end of the CREATE TRIGGER statement, and thinks the whole statement ends there. So you have to change the delimiter like this:

```
/* Change the delimiter */
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON ColdStorage.ReservationDetails
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.creationdate = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') then 
        insert into master_ids values ('0','0','0','0');
    END if;
END$$
/* the CREATE TRIGGER statement ends with new delimiter */

/* change the delimiter back to ; */
DELIMITER ;
```

I haven't tested it, but it seems fine. What bothers me is that this will work just for one day during the year, the other 364 (365) days it is completely useless, and looks like an overhead.

Comment: Its working . but problem is how do i test it. creation date is SYSDATE

Comment: I hope you have the test environment where you can create this trigger with todays date, instead of 01. January. Then, if it works today, there's no reason why it shouldn't work on 01.01. any year.